# In C# what does the &< logical operator mean?

Tags: c#, operators

Reading through the brief overview of C# from [Quick C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4300/Quick-C) when I stumbled across the "&<" logical operator. The particular snippet of code is as follows:

```
object[] objects = new object[2];
objects[0] = "Aisha";
object[1] = new Shape();

string str;
for(int i=0; i&< objects.Length; i++)
{
    str = objects[i] as string;
    if(str == null)
        Console.WriteLine("can not be converted");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",str);
}
```

I'm not sure what the operator means.

Comment: It's a typo. It should be `i < objects.Length`. There's also a typo at `object[1] = new Shape();`

Comment: It seems like the code won't even compile... because of the `object[1]` and `i&<`. Perhaps it is a **documentation error**. It does not seem to be a user-defined operator as well (this might not even possible too, due to no operator overload for that), because the items used are `int` and `object` - both are built-in items and do not have operator for `&<`.

Comment: Thanks guys. That's a shame that it's a typo. I was hoping to have the chance to learn a new operator.